# Why doesn't this comparison between character arrays work?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, operators

```
char a[1][2];
char b[1][2];

a[0][0] = 'a';
a[0][1] = 'b';
b[0][0] = 'a';
b[0][1] = 'b';

if(a[0] == b[0]){
   cout << "worked\n";
}
```

So as far as I can tell, this comparison between arrays of characters doesn't work the way you would expect it to. The if statement does not execute because the condition `a == b` returns false. Why is this?

Comment: You are comparing memory addresses.... They are POINTERS.

Comment: memory addresses are different for array a and b.

Comment: Correction: They **decay** into pointers. Anyway, this was inherited from C. For code that looks more like C++, use `std::string`.

Comment: @chris, I find that I have to use a lot of substring manipulation when I use std::string. For my purposes, the char array seems to work much better.

Comment: check this :http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memcmp/

Comment: Please create another separate question with the performance issues you see in using `std::string`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this statement

```
if(a == b){
   cout << "worked\n";
}
```

a and b are implicitly converted to pointers to first elements of the corresponding arrays. So there is a comparison of two pointers. As the arrays occupy different areas in memory then the condition will be alwasy equal to false.

There is no such an operation as the comparison for arrays. To compare two arrays you have toc compare all elements of the arrays with each other. For example you could use standard algorithm std::equal. For example

```
if( std::equal( std::begin( a ), std::end( a ), std::begin( b ) ) ){
   cout << "worked\n";
}
```

Another approach is to use standard container std::array that has the comparison operator. For example

```
std::array<char, 2> a = { 'a', 'b' };
std::array<char, 2> b = { 'a', 'b' };

    if(a == b){
       cout << "worked\n";
    }
```

Comment: I considered a and b as one-dimensional arrays in the expression in the statement with std::equal. Otherwise the code would be more compound.

Answer (score 4):

You can not compare arrays like that. You need to iterate over the arrays and compare each pair of elements in turn. Alternatively(and preferably) replace the static array with `std::vector`. The code you show compares the **pointers** `a` and `b` which of course are not equal.

Comment: So would the comparison if(*a[0] == *b[0]) work as expected? Is there any downside to using this method?

Comment: @user3150601 no it will not work and this is the main downside.

Comment: I edited the code and my question, does this refined one work?

Comment: No it does not `a[0]` is still an array. You can not compare arrays like that. However you can use `strcmp` to compare character arrays.

Comment: @user3150601, [Arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4810664/how-do-i-use-arrays-in-c) (please read that) decay into a pointer to the first element in a few circumstances. Therefore, you are comparing the first character only with both `*a` and `a[0]`.

Comment: @chris thank you! I'll check it out (and strcmp seems to be what I'm looking for here).

Comment: @chris not the first character but the address of the first character in the cases you show.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, Woops, I forgot it was a 2D array. That's right, so the first element is again, an array. The `*a[0]`, posted in the first comment, would then compare the first character only.

Comment: @chris in fact OP edited the content of the comment it used to be `a[0] == b[0]`

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev, Good point, I had a nudge in the back of my mind that it used to be different.

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev `strcmp` won't work in his case; `strcmp` requires `'\0'` terminated char sequences, _not_ just any character array.  (In this special case, `memcmp` would work.)

Comment: Well in case there is no terminating `\0` you may either use `strncmp` or `memcmp` as you suggest. Still I think using `string` or `vector` is a way better option